# Is there a forever.js equivalent for PHP to run my scripts continuously?

Tags: php, node.js, forever

I occasionally use [forever.js](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) for quick and dirty deploying of CLI type Node.js applications to production environments where I don't want a full on [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) deployment.

I was wondering if there was an equivalent for PHP?  At the moment we have a queue processing system that get's messages from [SQS](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) and processes them synchronously into a database (it can't be done async as that causes all sorts of nasty row locking issues in this particular use case.)  At the moment it runs ever minute using cron, but it often finishes early and I want it to start running again.  I can't have more than one process running at a time.

Any *nix command/software/bash type ideas are welcome.

Comment: Why not use forever.js to start your PHP script?

Comment: doh! didn't think about that will give it a go.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just use `forever` with your php script (use the `-c` argument to instruct forever to use `php`):

```
$ cat test.php
<?php
sleep(3);
print("foobar\n");
exit;
?>
$ forever -c php test.php
foobar
error: Forever detected script was killed by signal: null
error: Forever restarting script for 1 time
foobar
error: Forever detected script was killed by signal: null
error: Forever restarting script for 2 time
...
```

Comment: Dude, I had no idea you could do this.  This fixes my problem.  Thanks!

Comment: holy crap really?? thats awesome!

Comment: This is honestly crazy! where am i suppose to donate for the project?!!

Comment: By the way, it turned out that `forever -c` is not putting the script at the background, i have to use screen to do that, something like `screen forever -c php myscript.php` and detach it to run "forever"!

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash screen was not meant for this, [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) was. Anyways, to run a script with forever as a daemon process use start action, like so: `forever start -c php mysqcript.php`. Make sure to specify log files for forever instance and script's STDOUT / STDERR, like so: `forever start -a -l /path/to/myscript_forever.log -o /path/to/myscript_out.log -e /path/to/myscript_err.log -c php myscript.php`

Comment: @SergeyLukin Thanks, You're 100% correct, please do NOT upvote my comment, Sergey's comment is the correct one, In fact i think it is the best answer to the question, I am not going to delete my comment in order to show the others where i have been mistaken!

Answer (score 2):

I've just discovered this tool [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) and it works great. I've used this [ratchet tutorial](http://socketo.me/docs/deploy#supervisor) to make it run in minutes !

If I remember correctly forever script do not restart when you reboot server ?

Comment: We've been using supervisord for about 8 months now and it's great, we actually use in combo with `foreverd`.  However because nearly all our stuff is moving over to docker we've actually found ourselves using docker's built in daemonizing tools eg: `-d --restart=always`