# Laravel: Running queue:listen continuously on Windows Azure Web App

Tags: php, laravel, azure, queue, laravel-artisan

I feel a little bit silly for asking this question but I can't seem to find an answer on the internet for this problem. After searching for several hours I figured out that on a linux server you use Supervisor to run "php artisan queue:listen" (either with or without daemon) continuously on your website to handle jobs pushed to the queue. This is all well and good, but what if I want to do this on a Windows Azure web app? After searching around the solutions I found were:

- Make a chron job to run "php artisan queue:listen" every minute (or every X minutes), I really dislike this solution and wanted to avoid it specially if the site gets more traffic;
- Add a WebJob that runs "php artisan queue:listen" continuously (the problem here is I don't know how to write the script for the WebJob...);

I want to ask you guys for help on to know which of these is the correct solution, if there is a better one and if the WebJob is the best one how do I write the script for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, Supervisor is a modern alternative to nohup (no hang up) with a few other bits and pieces tacked on. In short, there's other resources that can keep a task running in the background (daemon) and the solution I use for Windows based projects (very few tbh) is Forever which I discovered via: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18226392/5912664

```
C:\myprojectroot > forever -c php artisan queue:listen --queue=some_nice_queue --tries=3
```

How?

Install `node` for Windows, then with `npm` install `Forever`

```
C:\myprojectroot > npm install -g forever
```

If you're stuck for getting Node running on Windows, I recommend the Windows Package Manager, `Chocolatey`

https://chocolatey.org/packages?q=node

Be sure to check for any logfiles that `Forever` creates, as I had left one long enough to consume 30Gb of disk space!

Comment: Thank you! I think this might solve the problem. If not's asking for too much, can you also tell me how do I write the php script that forever will run? Because I need to call the command "php artisan queue:listen" and I don't know how to call it from a php file outside of laravel.

Comment: I'm assuming you can access a CMD or PS shell? This command is run from the command line and you don't have to write a PHP script because the `artisan` file is included with Laravel by default. If you need a PHP script to execute / boot this method, take a look at http://www.php.net/function.shell_exec

Comment: This looked promising but alas... it doesn't work on IIS 7.5.

Comment: @suncoastkid , it doesn't require IIS to run, forever is it's own task runner. Simply keep your background script(s) alive with forever and serve your web based content through IIS. Works with a number of Laravel based apps I've written! :)

Comment: I have use this command "forever -c php artisan queue:listen redis" , Now cmd pops up and disappear continuously . How can stop this?
OS: windows
laravel 5.2

Comment: @JustinOriginBroadband see Mohammad's comment. That's what I meant by "doesn't work on IIS 7.5." Except in my case they don't close so the screen fills up with infinite cmd prompts.  Do you know of a fix?

Comment: @MohammadTasneemFaizyab You should use  **`start`**  when registering the command. So it would look like this:
 `forever start -c php artisan queue:listen --queue=some_nice_queue --tries=3`

Comment: @MohammadTasneemFaizyab I'm now facing the same issue, did you solve it last time?

Answer (score 4):

For Azure you can make a new webjob to your web app, and upload a .cmd file including a command like this.

```
php %HOME%\site\wwwroot\artisan queue:work --daemon
```

and defining that as a triguered and 0 * * * * * frequency cron.

that way work for me.

best.

Comment: Web jobs for App Services have just 4 properties: Name, File Upload, Type and Scale. Did you check if your php path, and modify this on your cmd file?

Comment: if is not the same that I sugest? You could also instal Kudu on your App Services and verify is all path are fine when you call artisan in this path.

Comment: Thanks @ErnestoLugo this is the azure way of doing it. Right now you can create a continuous and triggered web job, continuous will keep the worker daemon running.

Comment: Since laravel 5.3, the --daemon flag is no longer necessary. queue:work is a daemon by default. You can use the --once flag to run only one job instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot use a WebJob with Laravel on Azure.  The Azure PHP Web App is hosted on Linux.  WebJobs do not work with Linux at this moment.

The best way to do chron jobs in Laravel on Azure is to create an Azure Logic App.  You use the Recurrence trigger and then a HTTP action to send a POST request to your Laravel Web App.  You use this periodic heartbeat to run whatever actions you need to do.  Be sure to add authentication to your POST request.

The next problem you will have is that POST will be synchronous so the work you are doing cannot be extensive or your HTTP request will time out or you will reach the time limit on PHP scripts (60 seconds).

The solution is not Laravel Jobs because here again you need something running in the background to process the queues.

The solution is also not PHP threads. The standard Azure PHP Web App does not support PHP Threads.  You can of course build your own Web App and enable PHP threads, but this is really swimming upstream.

You simply have to live with synchronous logic.  So the work you are doing with the heartbeat should take no more than about 60 seconds.

If you need more extensive processing then you really need to off load it to another place: another Web App, an Azure Function, etc.

But why not do that in the first place?  The reason is cost and complexity.  If you have something simple...like a daily report...you simply connect the report to the heartbeat and all the facilities for producing the report are right there in Laravel.  To separate the daily report into its own container would require setup and the Web App it runs in would incur costs...not worth it in my view for something simple.