# Laravel queues in Azure server

Tags: windows, laravel, azure, queue, azure-webjobs

I'm really struggling with this issue, which is a little frustrating to me because it seems to be so simple in a Linux server. I have a Windows Azure Web App and I want to run "php artisan queue:listen" on the server continuously to take care of dispatched jobs. From what I read from the documentation, in Linux you just use Supervisor to run the command constantly and to revive it, in case it dies. From what I found online, Azure has a similar functionality called WebJobs where you can serve them a script to be ran and then decide whether it should run on a schedule or continuously (kinda like the Scheduler in Laravel). With this I have 2 questions.

- 1 - Is this the right solution? Place a script to run the command on a WebJob and have the WebJob run continuously?
- 2 - I'm not experienced in writing php scripts to run command lines, so all I can do is something like this:

> echo shell_exec('php artisan queue:work');

Problem is this does not give me the output of the command (I don't see anything like the "processed" result that I see when I run the command by hand on my command console and a job is processed). It is important to me to be able to read the output of the command, because I want to be able to check the logs for errors in case something happens when a job isn't able to be processed. From the documentation shell_exec returns null in case an error is thrown so I'm completely clueless on how to deal with this.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `shell_exec()` you can directly upload .cmd file which includes your command `php artisan queue:work`, and then you can find the output log in **WebJob Details** page.

About how to do that, please check [Ernesto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37729662/laravel-running-queuelisten-continuously-on-windows-azure-web-app/42441829#42441829) out.

> For Azure you can make a new webjob to your web app, and upload a .cmd
>   file including a command like this.
>
> `php %HOME%\site\wwwroot\artisan queue:work --daemon`
>
> and defining that as a triguered and `0 * * * * *` frecuency cron.
>
> that way work for me.

For more information, please refer to [Run Background tasks with WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service-mobile%2Ftoc.json#overview).